# Doxygen not generating `modules.tex` with `LAYOUT_FILE`

Tags: doxygen

Example: https://gist.github.com/4057143

System: Kubuntu 12.04 (+ `sudo apt-get install doxygen texlive-fonts-recommended`)

When running Doxygen with a custom layout file (specified via `CUSTOM_LAYOUT` in the Doxyfile) it does not generate the `modules.tex` file (and consequently fails to build the LaTeX output).  If I run Doxygen without the custom layout it generates the modules file which can be used if Doxygen is rerun with the custom layout...  I see no errors in the Doxygen output.

How can I make Doxygen create `modules.tex` while using a custom layout file?